# alter column with default value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
alter table enquiry alter  column RejectReson int default 0
```

I want alter the column data type with default value zero,but it is not happening.

Comment: "it is not happening." - well, what *is* happening? Do you get an error message (if so, what?). Or different behaviour than you expected (if so, what?)

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'default'.

Comment: getting this type of error

Comment: CHANGE is not working in sql server

Comment: @Tanner Not a valid dupe there, OP already has the column and wants to alter it, not add a new column.

Comment: @Tanner Probably should have left it, dupe targets are easily edited after the fact :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ADD CONSTRAINT`.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE enquiry ADD CONSTRAINT some_name DEFAULT 0 FOR RejectReson;
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE enquiry ADD DEFAULT 0 FOR RejectReson

Answer (score 0):

If you want to affect existing rows, then use `with values`:

```
alter table enquiry
    add constraint dft_enquiry_rejectreason default 0 with values;
```

This is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql):

> . . . `WITH VALUES` can be used to store the default value in the new column for each existing row in the table.